# Showing that closed and bounded does not imply compactness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

How can I show that the interval $\{x \in \mathbb{Q} : 0 ≤ x ≤ 1 \}$ is closed and bounded but
not compact with respect to the metric space $(\mathbb{Q}, | · |)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are considering
$$X= \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$$

$X$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$, since it is the intersection of $\mathbb{Q}$ with a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

$X$ is also bounded in $\mathbb{Q}$, since for all $x \in X$, you have $|x|\leq 1$.

But $X$ is not compact, because if it was, it would be as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but it is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Or, if you prefer, you can construct explicitely a sequence of elements of $X$ which has no limit point in X : for example, define
$$x_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$